# Is there a way to setup a Snowpipe on multiple Azure Storage Accounts?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My company set up multiple storage accounts (about 30) for an app with the same container name on the same Azure tenant ID (ex. azure://myaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/samecontainername,
azure://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/samecontainername,
azure://myaccount3.blob.core.windows.net/samecontainername)

I've created Snowpipes in the past and the process was:

1. Create a queue on the account and container
2. Create an Event Grid linked to that account and container and with a destination set as the created queue
3. Create a Notification Integration in Snowflake (to a queue related to that account and container)
4. Authenticate the service principal app Snowflake created (if it is the first time on that tenant ID)
5. Create a stage using the account and blob url (azure://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/samecontainername) and using the notification integration created
6. Create a pipe using the notification integration created and copy from the stage created into a variant table (for Json files)

The question is, is there a way to simplify this so I won't have to do the steps above 30 times? Each account contains the same container name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not as snowpipe can have one NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION per queue. However, we have setup a copy statement from all accounts into one not used for PROD on which we set up a NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION to Snowflake and then a PIPE using that integration